# Add menu in custom module odoo 9

Tags: menu, odoo, odoo-9

I want to add in my custom module a menu link to CONTACT.

```
web?#view_type=kanban&model=res.partner&menu_id=99&action=97
```

What is the ID in ACTION for that?

```
<menuitem name="Member" id="" action="" parent="my_custom_menu" sequence="16"/>
```

In Settings => Technical => User Interface => Menu Items I don't see MENU ID after open any menu item.

Comment: For that you need to assign action.
Menu item only show on the view when there is a action associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_partner_form">
     <field name="name">Partner</field>
     <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
     <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
</record>

<menuitem name="My Partner" id="my_partner_menu" action="action_partner_form" parent="my_parent_menu" sequence="21"/>
```